# When IIS restarts how to go back to same page?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Suppose I have logged into an web application. I'm on the page Default.aspx. If iis restarts then I need to re-login to use the application.

Is it possible to go back to the same page if IIS restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the ASP.Net application domain recycles, you're issue is that you're losing session state data, right? If that's the case, then how about storing session data in the StateServer or inside SQL Server? The default is "in process", so it's wiped clean when the app domain recycles.

Answer (score 3):

How are you authenticating your users? Using forms authentication stores a client side cookie which can survive IIS resetting. Are you storing any authentication information in session state perhaps?

## Edit

Just to add you can also redirect a user to a different page from the login page. Take the following url `http://example.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx`.

This URL can be used to redirect the user to the Default.aspx page after they login. Assuming your using Forms authentication you can then redirect them using FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false); The false parameter prevents a persistant cookie from being created.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a cookie on each page the user vists stating which page they were on, then in your OnLoggedIn event you can check for the existance of this cookie, and redirect the user to the page - we use a similar mechanism for round-robin logins to multiple domains at once.